# How will be implemented minimal garbage collection support in a future C++1x?

Tags: c++, c++11, garbage-collection, iso

I've just seen Herb Sutter's presentation Future C++ and there was mentioned that he and some other people work on the garbage collection proposal.Straustrup has already mentioned several reasons for minimal garbage collection support. I've also found one: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AlgorithmsThatDemandGarbageCollection
I tried to google information about the implementation details of future garbage collection, but found only old proposals (2005-2007) accordingly to them garbage collection will be implemented via special kind of pointers (something similar to C++\CLI and C++\CX I guess). But nevertheless what is now?

Can somebody clearify for me this. What kind of garbage collection will be in a future C++? Links to some useful and new articles and proposals with technical details will be appreciated and very helpful!

Comment: Why "at last"? Have you been missing garbage collection? The C++ solution is simply not to produce garbage in the first place.

Comment: @KerrekSB I know all this quite perfect. I'm a C++ programmer for a long time. I only want to know some new information about the proposals on which people are working now and how this minimal support will be implemented because couldn't find information myself

Comment: @AlexanderKaraberov: just look at the working drafts of WG21, starting from the revision I gave. It was already planned to be added to C++0x, they just couldn't do it in time. So, like concept, they threw it away to finish at least *something*...

Comment: I believe the short answer right now is, nobody really knows. They formed a new study group on concurrency; I'd be *almost* surprised if that study group didn't include some sort of garbage collection in what it's working on (GC is extremely useful for concurrency, and unless my memory's working even worse than usual, I believe Hans Boehm is chairing the concurrency study group).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard will not "implement garbage collection". It will describe the interaction of a conforming C++ program with a garbage collector. In particular, the existing wording that, as far as I remember, was already in the working draft for C++0x, described what safely derived pointers are (that is which pointers the garbage collector can find), it said that garbage collection is optional, and that it does not call destructors. It *did not* add any new kind of pointers.

**EDIT:** the N2960 draft had this wording in it. You can do binary search to find the latest version.